# How to increment a counter inside of a loop

Tags: php, loops, increment

I don't understand, I have a variable `$i` which is not incrementing in my loop.

```
while ($ligne = mysqli_fetch_array($resu2,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
        for($i = 1; $nbjour >= $i; $i++)
        {
            while ($ligne2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resu3,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $element=$ligne2['jourIndisponibilite'];
                echo "1er ".$element;
                echo "2eme ".$ligne['idSPProfessionnel'];
                echo ' ';
                echo $i;
                echo ' ';
                if ($ligne2['jourIndisponibilite']==$i && $ligne['idSPPprofessionnel']==$ligne2['idSpProfessionnel']){ 
                    echo '<td height=25>';
                    echo 'X';
                    echo '</td>';
                }
            }
            echo '<td height=20></td>';
        }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
echo '</br>';
?>
```

Comment: `$i` is incremented with each iteration of the `for` loop, certainly not with the inner `while` loop.

Comment: What is `$nbjour`?

Comment: $nbjour = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 05, 2017);  // nombre de jour dans le mois